# Finding matches between words in file allowing one mismatch

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to find matching words in a file allowing one mismatch between words, I put here a part of the file and the expected output I want to obtain.

The file I want to parse looks like this:

```
CTAGGA
TTAGCT
CGTACA
ACAGTG
ACACTG
```

And the output I want to obtain is something similar to this:

```
CTAGGA: CTAGGA
TTAGCT: TTAGCT
CGTACA: CGTACA
ACAGTG: ACAGTG, ACACTG
ACACTG: ACAGTG, ACACTG
```

The output doesn't need to be exactly like this, but something understandable of which words have <=1 mismatch. I DON'T want a match between something like CTAGGA and CTGGAC, where they would match if the second word was something like CT**A**GGAC.

Thank you very much

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code as your efforts in your question. Mentioning efforts in question is highly encouraged in stack overflow, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Read about [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

Comment: please well-define what is a mismatch. your description is ambiguous and a bit confusing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build a solution step-by-step by solving the *subproblems*.

**Problem 1:** Levenhstein distance (Editing distance). agrep has it built-in.

```
agrep -1 "ACATTG" dna.file
```

**Problem 2:** Reading the file line by line

```
#!/bin/bash 
#pass file as argument

while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do
    echo "processing line: ${LINE}"
done < $1
```

call with: `./script.sh <absolutepathtoyourgenomefile>`

**Problem 3:** Combining it together and building the output.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#pass file as argument

file=$1

while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do
    echo "${LINE}:" $(agrep -1 "${LINE}" $file)
done < $file
```

**Example:**

Inputfile `/tmp/genome.txt`

```
CTAGGA
TTAGCT
CGTACA
ACAGTG
ACACTG
TCAGGA
TTAAGG
TTGGAA
TTAGCA
TTGGAA
TTAGGA
```

Run script:

```
$ ./script.sh /tmp/genome.txt 

CTAGGA: CTAGGA TCAGGA TTAGGA
TTAGCT: TTAGCT TTAGCA
CGTACA: CGTACA
ACAGTG: ACAGTG ACACTG
ACACTG: ACAGTG ACACTG
TCAGGA: CTAGGA TCAGGA TTAGGA
TTAAGG: TTAAGG TTAGGA
TTGGAA: TTGGAA TTGGAA
TTAGCA: TTAGCT TTAGCA TTAGGA
TTGGAA: TTGGAA TTGGAA
TTAGGA: CTAGGA TCAGGA TTGGAA TTAGCA TTGGAA TTAGGA
```

Note, that 'one mismatch' is highly ambiguous. What metric do you use to define what is 'one' mismatch?

Does that solve your question?